# Android Debugging with Eclipse - No Breakpoints

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug a simple Android application on either the emultor or a device and I cannot get the debugger to stop on any breakpoints I have set.  I have combined the other posts here and throughout the web and tried all the suggestions (Add debuggable:"true" to the manifest, stop and start adb, Clean all, make sure I use the debug button not the run button, etc etc).  In the Debug perspective I can see the threads and in DDMS it shows the debug icon next to the device I am debugging on.  I do see the blue dots where I set the breakpoint and the Debug perspective lists them and says they are active.

I have put in alerts just before the breakpoints to verify the code is getting executed.

Starting to go crazy here.  Any other suggestions?  I must be missing something simple but non-obvious.

UPDATE:  I appreciate the responses so far. Unfortunately they have not solved my problem.  I have followed the instruction on debugging and have debugging turned on in the phone.  Also, I do see the "Waiting for debugger" alert on the phone when starting.  In general everything says I am debugging (including getting logcat output that I have added).  It just will not stop on breakpoints that I have added and are listed in the breakpoints tab in the Debug perspective.  Also just to reiterate - this happens when debugging on the device as well as on the emulator.  One thing I do notice is that when I launch the debugger I have it set to bring up the Android Device Chooser.  In there the "debug" column is blank for my device - but if the emulator is running the debug column does say 'Yes'.  Also the console states that is attempting to connect to the debugger.  Should there be a console log that states that the debugger successfully connected?  I do not see this.

UPDATE 20120914: I have been away from this for some time and had given up previously.  Back to try and tackle this.  It is still not resolved.  Everything above is still current - but one other thing I have noticed. I set a Class Load Breakpoint on the main activity and it does stop there.  It just does not stop at any Line Breakpoints.  I have just updated to the latest JDK 1.7.0_07, Android SDK 20, ADT Plugin 20.0.3. I have used the logcat to output a message and set a breakpoint on this line.  I see the message in logcat so I know the code is being executed.  The debug window in the debig perspective also does show the android application with a number of threads beneath it and the Devices window in the DDMS perspective shows the application with the green bug icon next to it.

One more thing - when the debugger is running the line breakpoints bullets do not get a checkmark overlaid on them (the Class Load Breakpoint does!).  I am guessing this is the root cause - but I don't know why they are not getting this. (By the way skip breakoints is also not set - breakpoints do not have lines through them).

Any new suggestions would be appreciated.  I have burned a lot of time on this.  It must be something obvious that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 5):

Now I feel a bit stupid writing this post.  But I resolved my issue finally.   The problem is you cannot set breakpoints in the Javascript code.  The part I left out unintentionally is I am writing an app for Android using PhoneGap.  Almost all the code is Javascript.  I am so used to developing .NET web apps in Visual Studio I just assumed you could set breakpoints in the javascript code.  Breakpoints in the Java code happen to work fine.  Anyway, Thanks for any suggestions. Do';t know if there are other .NET developers trying PhoneGap development - but maybe this post will help them.

Answer (score 3):

Android SDK provides most of the tools that you need to debug your applications. This link will introduce you to [Android debugging environment and the debugging tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html) used.

Here's also a hands on tutorial on [**debugging an android application**.](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7491/)

If you want to ***debug using actual android phone***, turn on "**USB Debugging**" in your device:

> Settings > Applications > Development and enable USB debugging

Android 4.0:

> Settings > Developer options

AND make use of `Log.d` and your `Logcat`.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a debug run configuration. Only if you use the debug run configuration will a debugger be attached with the application during launch.

Does the application launch (on the device/emulator) pause a while "Waiting for Debugger" ? If not, then you are not launching the application using "debug configuration". Its the button to the immediate left of run (drop down) configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try jsHybugger: http://www.jshybugger.org/ for setting javascript breakpoints in Eclipse for remote(mobile) devices.

It lets you set breakpoints, singlestep, catch exceptions, and interact with the JS/DOM environment. You can use it from Eclipse or from a Chrome or Chrome-compatible debugger on the remote desktop. It can be used with apps that create their own webView.

However, you have to install a few files -- but probably no more complicated to use than weinre. it does extensively modify the JS files (on the fly, transparently to the user) to enable all this debugging -- webKit really should support javascript debugging natively.

Comment: This is not a relevant answer to the question. At least I can's see webview/phonegap/javascript mentioned anywhere else than in another answer.

Comment: I think it is relevant in that he was asking ultimately about how to debug javascript in an app (not java in an app as the initial question might have implied.    This is the only way I have found to be able to debug (breakpoint/singlestep) javascript (in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not check skip all breakpoints (Run -> Skip all breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

Ribo already mentions it in his answer, but since this question and answers are about debugging Phonegap applications.
You certainly have to look at weinre (WEb INspector REmote). 
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Nowadays phonegap even has it's own weinre embraced in phonegap build...
http://debug.phonegap.com/

I Am a big fan of this... (note if you are using weinre on your local machine and trying to debug a phonegap app via wifi... make sure your local device is on the same wifi network!)